# How do you show a notification on connected device but not wearable device?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a notification in my app that has actions associated with it.  When a user clicks one of the actions, after a successful post to the server, there is a follow up confirmation message.  On a wearable device, this follow up is wonky and just shows the "Block app" option, then dismisses.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is how Gmail works when you archive a message.  On the wearable once you click "Archive" it just shows the green success check then dismisses.  On your device if you click "Archive" it gives you the follow up notification in the shade of "Archived".

I have tried to add blank extended notification with no success as follows:

```
//build phone notification
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
           this).setContentTitle(getString(R.string.great_job))
...
NotificationCompat.Action blankAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(0, null, null).build();
builder.extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction(blankAction));
...
builder.build();
```

TIA

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question?